80s-90s movie featuring a genius teen with scenes involving video hacking and a nuclear weapon discussion
I'm searching for the title of a movie:

It is an 80s-90s movie (could be younger).

English language.

Most likely a US movie.

I watched this movie in a bus in maybe 2005, but the image was not as clean as a 2000s movie. I could be wrong about that.

Plot details: The movie is about a teenager who is pretty smart but he uses his mind to trick people. I remember one scene in which he "hacked" a video system that broadcast a video in a loop to remove the wig of the person on the video. Maybe this was some ATM network; I'm not sure about that.


I also remember a scene where someone (parental figure? professor?) is arguing with him and pointing out the fact that he could construct a nuclear weapon for fun.
I think the teenager doesn't live with his parents (maybe they are dead? Or maybe he is like a rich foster child?).
Also, the teen isn't very well integrated, I think. He wears formal clothes, not like the kids of his age, but once again, I'm not really sure. I could be mixing details from other movies.
It's not War Games

Could it be The Manhattan Project (1986)?



In it, a teenage boy constructs a homemade nuclear bomb using radioactive material stolen from a nearby facility, where his mother's boyfriend (John Lithgow) works.

Thanks for your answer. No it's not this movie. The nuclear weapon scene I'm talking about, was just a small scene, and it was just used to point out that the teenager has no limits and that he has to think before acting. It's not because he could do something that he should do it.
